# R Package to meta-analysis using HKSJ method

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta-analysis for small-number of studies (2-5). I found the Hartung-Knapp-Sidik-Jonkman method is more appropriate for a meta-analysis with a few studies. However, I did not find any packages on R which can do it. Would you please share anyone help me on this?

I tried another method for meta-analysis as I did not find package for HKSJ method.

Answer (score 0):

I found `metafor` package can do it.
Need to add `test="knha"` in rma:

```r
res <- rma(lnhr, sei=se, data=dffc, method="REML", test="knha", weighted = TRUE)
```